# Why isn't my sound file getting copied to?

Tags: file, indexing, audio

so i wrote a code that creates two sound files, gives some details and explores them, but I'm having difficulty with a part thats meant to create a third sound file with length of the longer of the first two sound files and the sampling rate of both (they have the same sr). The function is meant to take the value of the samples of all indices of the first two sound files, add them together, and copy them into the third sound file. I thought I had it, but when i explore the third file it comes up blank.

```
def sound():
  a = pickAFile()
  b = pickAFile()

  sound1 = makeSound(a)
  sound2 = makeSound(b)

  sr1 = getSamplingRate(sound1)
  sr2 = getSamplingRate(sound2)

  printNow(sr1)
  printNow(sr2)

  play(sound1)
  play(sound2)

  explore(sound1)
  explore(sound2)

  if sr1 == sr2:
    printNow('Sampling Rate 1: %d \nSampling Rate 2: %d' % (sr1, sr2))
  else:
    printNow('Sampling Rates are not equal.')
  c=getLength(sound1)
  d=getLength(sound2)
  printNow('sound1: %d, sound2: %d' % (c, d))
  sound3 = Sound(getLength(sound2), int(sr1))

  for index in range(0, getLength(sound1)): 
    value = getSampleValueAt(sound1, index)

  for index in range(0, getLength(sound2)):
    value2 = getSampleValueAt(sound2, index)

  for index in range(0, getLength(sound3)):  
    setSampleValueAt(sound3, index, value+value2)

  play(sound3)
  explore(sound3)
```

Comment: I think you should add tags for what language you are using and what libraries you are relying on, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is python (?). I don't know python, but it's clear that the problem lies in this part of your code:

```
for index in range(0, getLength(sound1)): 
    value = getSampleValueAt(sound1, index)
for index in range(0, getLength(sound2)):
    value2 = getSampleValueAt(sound2, index)
for index in range(0, getLength(sound3)):  
    setSampleValueAt(sound3, index, value+value2)
```

Assuming you've indented correctly, you are using three separate loops, so the last loop loops through your target file and sets all the sample values to the sum of the last values it found. You should only use one loop. Something more like this:

```
for index in range(0, MIN( getLength(sound1), getLength(sound2) ) ):
    value = getSampleValueAt(sound1, index)
    value2 = getSampleValueAt(sound2, index) 
    setSampleValueAt(sound3, index, value+value2)
```

(whatever min is in python) and of course, you should set the value of length of the created file to he minimum as well. Of course there are other ways to solve the issue of mismatched file lengths, but first fix the problem with your loops.